# ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.PurchaseParams

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have several apps on the market and iaps are working like a charm. I'm working on a new app right now.

During testing I keep getting an error:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.PurchaseParams

The app is published on store right now. I had to change the code of iaps due to changes in my app on the side of my server. So now I just sign the changed app with the developer key leaving the version code and name the same. This way the app store thinks this is the published version even when it has different code. I used to do this on all my apps. I make regular purchases to test if it's working.

The purchase goes through fine. I'm being charged for the purchase and I receive an email from the market. The problem is my app should send information to my server in onPurchaseStateChange. But this never happens. Same thing with purchaseResponse. I have a couple lines of code that should be logging information and it's not there.

When I saw this for the first time I tried changing the code. It started working and then stopped again.

All the time I'm getting this error. It does not crash the app and the purchase itself is made.

If anyone knows what's going on please let me know. Thx!

Comment: This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161682/in-app-billing-fails-in-new-version-of-my-app

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I have the exact same problem, in fact my published version also has this problem. So purchases go through but my OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener is never called, so the purchase is never activated immediately. The funny part is that the purchase is registered on the Google server, so if the user re-opens the app, he can see the purchase.

Comment: Happened to me when i'm trying to purchase an invalid inapp product.