# Google IAB return purchase error type=3 subtype=4

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

When I tried to buy all of items, then it returns the message like bellow

> "The item you requested is not available for purchase."

And logcat logs.

> 09-04 10:06:25.374: D/Finsky(7185): [1](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#billing-codes) PurchaseFragment.handleError:
>   Error: PurchaseError{type=3 subtype=4} 09-04 10:06:25.374:
>   D/Finsky(7185): [1](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#billing-codes) PurchaseFragment.fail: Purchase failed:
>   PurchaseError{type=3 subtype=4}

I guess, purchase error code type 3 is [billing api problem](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#billing-codes)

> BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE   3   Billing API version is
>   not supported for the type requested

But... It is a live app in GooglePlayStore and I could buy an item yesterday. 
And also it seems that most user can buy items. So I think the hint is **subtype=4**. But I can't find information about subtypes.

FYI, The application region locked in my country. Is it the problem? But I can't find Google's announcement about it.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense if subtype=4 was referring to that table in the docs that you linked to? In that case 4 would be BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_UNAVAILABLE "Requested product is not available for purchase" which matches the message you saw.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have the same error , and fix the problem in this way :
In the APK section . Now tester email must be listed as testers in either Alpha or Beta Testing . 
After add a tester list . the tester need to open the 'Join Test' url , after join the test , I can test the purchase .

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Ok, I request check about it. I can't remember about open Join Test url. But I can check again if listed as tester.

Comment: the tester need to open the test url :https://play.google.com/apps/testing/your-package-name.                                                                              And maybe need to install the apk from the web .  And need to wait the package published (few hour after  publish button click ).

Comment: Sorry for late. But It doesn't help it. Please check above comment of user1454444's ans.

Comment: if your  country can't access the app in google market . it mean you could not test the app . need to fix this first . and than download the test app in the :play.google.com/apps/testing/your-package-name

Comment: I agree with you. But there are no google's notice, information or description that can't access the app in my country...

Comment: check the phone language  setting . google wallet setting .  app sale country. and connect the USA VPN or other area which  in the sale country

Comment: I have tried to change phone langauge into Engish, set google wallet adress, and connect via USA vpn. but It didn't help anything. Always same result. lol. Still item not found in google play market.

Comment: But in these case, I got an error 'PurchaseFragment.onStateChange: Purchase failed: PurchaseError{type=3 subtype=0}'.

It is different than previous error {type=3 subtype=4}. Interesting...

Comment: Finally I can find my app on Google Play Store app. before searching, I have cleared app data of Google Play Store app. Good. And also I can buy an Item. 'type=3 subtype=0' issue seems to signed app issue.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like Google changed their IAP policies again and now users must be listed as testers in either Alpha or Beta Testing.  From there you must opt-in (log in to that Google account and go to the URL for your app in the Google Developer Console).  I ran into the same issue and that was their recommendation.

> Since our update things have changed a bit. This account will need to make sure and opt-in to the new testing-link.

Just confirmed that this fixed the issue.  You must configure Alpha/Beta testers for each app you have in the developer console in order for those users to be able to make test purchases.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But unfortunately, I tested it both of test and normal accounts. And I got the same results.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work.  Just to be certain, when you say test account, you do mean a user that is part of a test group configured in the Developer console AND said user has clicked on the opt-int link required?  I mention this because this was my exact issue and making sure the test set up was configured properly in the developer console AND that the user was part of the test was what fixed it.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Ok, I request check about it. I can't remember about clicking opt-int link. So I check it again. Thanks ;)

Comment: ;( Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem. Actually, My country can't access the app in google market. I just can see 'We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server.'. But real USA user can see it, download it or buy it

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this error response when I published a new alpha/beta version of an app to the developer console, but it hasn't finished processing yet.

[image: Play Store console "Processing Update"]

Try again in an hour or so - make sure you have opted in to be an alpha/beta tester and that you can see the appropriate alpha/beta version of the app in the Play Store and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to user1454444, make sure you don't have the publisher account on the device either - It was always the case that the publisher account couldn't buy IAPs which meant you couldn't have the main account on the device to be the publisher account, if you were testing.

I have recently (like literally over the last weekend) discovered that even having the publisher account on at all - i.e. your main account is not the publisher, but the publisher account is on the device - this will cause a fail in the buying process.

Comment: Cool! I used a publisher account, published the other app, as a test account. I will try to make a new account as test account.

Comment: Sorry for late. But It doesn't help it. Please check above comment of user1454444's ans.

Comment: Also, make sure the version code is the same one as the live version.

Comment: Sure. I've checked it. It's fine. I guess, this is rely on regional restrictions. works fine in NA ;(

Answer (score -1):

I suffered with this issue but it solved very simply.
The real problem was "*You cannot try billing test with developer account*", even that was invited account from project owner. Only, none associated account can be tested for purchasement.

Here is another checklist I had tried.

1. Is Registered in Gameservice -> Test -> tester
2. Is Registered in Alpha or beta tester at 
    *AppVersion->Alpha/Beta Management->Tester*
3. Are there No developer account in chrome, g-mail, playstore, googlePlay? (Every developer account must be cleaned)
4. Is App published? (at lest as close alpha/beta)
5. Did you install app with invitation url?
6. Check base64 key, packagename.
7. Is item activated?