# What is required to successfully perform in-app purchases using the Playscape SDK?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, playscape

Having updated the Playscape SDK version to 1.14.160 for Unity, for our Unity android game Zombie Snipe, we have run into issues trying to perform in-app purchases in the google store. The error message we receive on the device (android, HTC M9) when attempting to perform a purchase, is the following:

```
"Error: The item you requested is not available for purchase."
```

The only change we have made since the last version of the SDK is to update the SDK, at which point the purchases were working.
We are using Unity version 454f1.

Answer (score 2):

This issue appeared thanks to google's recently changed rules for tester accounts. Testers now need to 'opt-in' in order to make test purchases.
This issue has been covered here: [Google IAB return purchase error type=3 subtype=4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32388978/google-iab-return-purchase-error-type-3-subtype-4)