# Subscription purchase issue with new accounts

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

My app is in the Play store for a long time and contains in app subscription purchase.
I've recently came across an issue, during our testing, of purchasing subscription through the app with new Google accounts.

This is the scenario:

1. Creating a new Google account and add it to the
2. Remove all other accounts to make sure we're gonna purchase with the new account (I've tried also the Play store app data clean)
3. Enter the app and try purchasing a subscription
4. It seems that the item is fetched properly from the Play store and shown. However after pressing "subscribe", we're getting the
   following error message: "Unfortunately, your transaction can't be
   completed at this time. Please try again"

We're using the latest iabHelper for integrating the store and subscriptions.

While debugging I've noticed few log messages that might be relevant.
When starting the purchase flow from the app (launchPurchaseFlow), I've seen the following messages on logcat:

```
 E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.PurchaseParams
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.PurchaseParams
      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
      at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2133)
      at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2097)
      at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2013)
      at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2314)
      at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249)
      at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1118)
      at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:5221)
      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1477)
      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1080)
      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:4600)
      at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:254)
      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:4481)
      at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:262)
      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2762)
      at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/android/finsky/billing/lightpurchase/PurchaseParams
      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251) 
      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216) 
      at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2133) 
      at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2097) 
      at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2013) 
      at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2314) 
      at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249) 
      at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1118) 
      at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:5221) 
      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1477) 
      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1080) 
      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:4600) 
      at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:254) 
      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:4481) 
      at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:262) 
      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2762) 
      at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method) 
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.PurchaseParams" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251) 
      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216) 
      at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2133) 
      at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2097) 
      at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2013) 
      at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2314) 
      at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249) 
      at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1118) 
      at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:5221) 
      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1477) 
      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1080) 
      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:4600) 
      at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:254) 
      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:4481) 
      at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:262) 
      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2762) 
      at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

When getting the error message from the Play store, I can see the following on logcat:

```
I/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.l.ao.run(138): Applying library update: account=[EHqg24VFVJk2mUDkHOexGliDIyk]
I/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.PurchaseFragment.a(22698): Error: PurchaseError{type=3 subtype=0}
```

Additional information:

- I've seen the issue happening every time for new user.
- However on a specific older user I've managed to purchase subscription once but encountered the issue the next time I've tried, so I'm not sure what's the scenario here.
- I'm using the same CC for our tests from multiple accounts, and it's a corporate CC

Comment: If "long time" is very long (several years), "use primary account for test" constraint may cause the issue. And check apps are not blocked for second  (sometimes fail) case. See https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: And this may help. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/70215/change-gmail-account-to-make-in-app-purchase

Comment: "ClassNotFoundException" related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161682/in-app-billing-fails-in-new-version-of-my-app