# Android static test purchase crashes

Tags: java, android, billing

I've been running into some problems trying to make a test-purchase from an Android app. I tried implementing in-app billing following the official tutorial, and then opted to use the [checkout](https://github.com/serso/android-checkout) library to make things easier on myself. Unfortunately, I've run into the exact same problem in both cases.

When I try to make a purchase, the android purchase popup will appear briefly, load for a moment, and then the app will crash. I can see the following error in logcat:

```
06-24 13:42:05.485 1558-2697/? E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.finsky.billing.common.PurchaseParams
                                         java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.finsky.billing.common.PurchaseParams
                                             at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                             at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2517)
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2471)
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2374)
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2727)
                                             at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:269)
                                             at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:992)
                                             at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:6702)
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityLocked(ActivityStarter.java:336)
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1097)
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:6275)
                                             at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:339)
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:6019)
                                             at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:298)
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3573)
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573)
                                          Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.finsky.billing.common.PurchaseParams
                                             at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                             at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:1346)
                                             at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:1406)
                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                             at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
                                             at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400) 
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2517) 
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2471) 
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2374) 
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2727) 
                                             at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:269) 
                                             at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:992) 
                                             at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:6702) 
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityLocked(ActivityStarter.java:336) 
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1097) 
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:6275) 
                                             at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:339) 
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:6019) 
                                             at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:298) 
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3573) 
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573) 
                                          Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available

06-24 13:42:05.504 614-4655/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
06-24 13:42:05.661 28655-28655/? E/Zygote: v2
06-24 13:42:05.663 28655-28655/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
06-24 13:42:05.707 1148-1329/? E/QC-NETMGR-LIB: Unsupported attribute type, ignoring 0x8
06-24 13:42:05.707 1148-1329/? E/QC-NETMGR-LIB: unrecognized ifindex 6
06-24 13:42:05.708 1148-1329/? E/QC-NETMGR-LIB: Unsupported attribute type, ignoring 0x8
06-24 13:42:05.708 1148-1329/? E/QC-NETMGR-LIB: unrecognized ifindex 6
06-24 13:42:05.742 4563-4677/? E/ContactsProvider_EventLog: Flush buffer to file cnt : 1 size : 0Kb duration : 7ms lastUpdatedAfter : 4014 ms mFlush_time_threasold : 2000 mCurrentSize : 487
06-24 13:42:05.938 21138-28711/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
                                                   Process: com.android.vending, PID: 21138
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'long com.google.wireless.android.finsky.dfe.nano.an.b' on a null object reference
                                                       at com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.s.a(SourceFile:5)
                                                       at com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.h.doInBackground(SourceFile:27)
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Using the checkout library, the actual code to make the purchase is very simple:

```
//SKU_PREMIUM is set to "android.test.purchased" and PURCHASE_DEVPAYLOAD is set to a random string of characters "T?ate755S,26B361Ml2nXxWW31H8Ex"
private final ActivityCheckout mCheckout = Checkout.forActivity(this, StethoApplication.getInstance().getBilling());
private Inventory mInventory;

private void configBilling() {
    mCheckout.start();

    mCheckout.createPurchaseFlow(new PurchaseListener());

    mInventory = mCheckout.makeInventory();
    mInventory.load(Inventory.Request.create()
            .loadAllPurchases()
            .loadSkus(ProductTypes.IN_APP, PremiumFragment.SKU_PREMIUM), new InventoryCallback());
}
public void purchasePremium() {
        mCheckout.whenReady(new Checkout.EmptyListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReady(BillingRequests requests) {
                requests.purchase(ProductTypes.IN_APP, PremiumFragment.SKU_PREMIUM, PremiumFragment.PURCHASE_DEVPAYLOAD, mCheckout.getPurchaseFlow());
            }
        });
    }
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161682/in-app-billing-fails-in-new-version-of-my-app) stack overflow post has the same issue, but that post is dealing with an actual "live" test purchase instead of a static test purchase. I've also seen a few posts say that you must be logged in to a different google account than your developer account, but again that's for testing "live" purchases.

Because I've had the same problem with my custom billing code as well as with the checkout library, I assume this is some type of config issue. I uploaded an alpha version of the app to google play and then use the public key from the developer console to initialize the library. I think this may be causing the problem, but I'm not sure.

If anybody could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I had the same problem with my own app and Play Store version 7.9.80.Q-all [0] [PR] 159305549. Uninstalling updates from Google Play Store solves the issue, but it's not a solution.

Comment: Uninstalling updates didn't fix it for me. Can I ask what OS version you guys are on? I'm seeing this on the Android O dev preview, but the same code seems to be working OK on other devices.

Comment: I'm seeing this using N on a Verizon Samsung Galaxy S7. However a (not so great) workaround is that you can upload the app to an alpha release on the play store, and then configure yourself to be a test account. This will let you test purchases without actually paying, but it's a big hassle.

Comment: I confirm the problem is still present and persists with Play Store version 8.0. Apparently the crash occurs only when using static responses to test in-app functionalities.